# How to set null for datetime

Tags: javascript

I have one field with type Date time in JavaScript and I would like set the field to `null` when user clicks button. I have tried using this script but it still doesn't work:

```
vars.$L_file.close_time="";
```

Is there any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting to null. And where are you storing the values?

```
vars.$L_file.close_time=null;
```